# GNU screen: how to resume my screen session reliably?

Tags: gnu-screen

I was unable to resume my screen session this morning, even after I killed the old screen -r session.

```
svtbuild@dvm-2:~/rfs$ screen -r 17757.pts-0.dvm-2
There is a screen on:
    17757.pts-0.dvm-2   (11/27/2012 04:49:19 PM)    (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 17757.pts-0.dvm-2.
```

After waiting for a while I was able to resume.  How can I do this more reliably?

Comment: From the screen manpage: `screen -D -R`.

Comment: @ott-- If this is the solution, can you post it as an answer with a short explanation of the flags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the screen manpage:

```
screen -D -R
Attach here and now. In detail this means: If a session is running, then reattach.
If necessary detach and logout remotely first. If it was not running create it
and notify the user.
```

As mentioned for the options `-D -RR`, unless you know the status of your session(s), you should check it with `screen -list`.